# Is sweating good for you?

Tags: sweat

Is sweating good for you?

My home office is rather hot. I have the option of installing a fan which would make it feel less hot, but I was wondering if just sweating while I work has any health benefits.

I know dehydration is dangerous, so I would be aware of this and be drinking water.

Answer (score 3):

According to this article: http://www.huffingtonpost.com/melissa-edmonds/does-sweating-release-tox_b_8372452.html, just sweating has no clear health benefits.

The health benefits of sweating come with exercise.